# Managing multiple hard drives, choosing which stores what (during install process)

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have an SSD and an HDD installed in my machine. I've decided to start fresh, and make a few changes in the process.

I would like to use the SSD for certain documents (project files) as well as the `/opt` directory, so all programs installed there would be installed to the SSD. The HDD would store all other files.

The configuration I had in mind was:

- Mounting point for `sdb[X]` is `/`
- Mounting point for `sda[X]` is `/opt`

(sda is SSD and sdb is HDD)

There is a few questions I have about this configuration.

1. Does it even work like that?
2. If I mount the SSD to `/opt`, where can I store my documents? Is it a good idea to store them in the `/opt` directory as well?
3. Assuming the answer to 2 is no, is it possible to place them outside the `/opt` directory but still on the same partition? Ideally I'd like the programs and the documents I mentioned above on the same partition, but I'll create a separate one if necessary.

---

In short, I'd like to move `/opt` and `~/Documents` to a secondary drive, and have all `/opt` programs automatically installed on it.

Comment: You could partition your SSD, mount 1 partition at `/opt` and use the other partition for `/home`, which is where your documents are being stored. The '~' in `~/Documents` means `/home/your-username`.

Comment: If I set the mounting point to `/home`, wouldn't that also include all other `/home/...` folders? (Downloads, Music, Movies, etc.) I should mount it to `/home/Documents`, right?

Comment: Yes it would include all of those other ones. There isn't a `/home/Documents` directory, Documents and all of those others are on a per user basis, so if your username is luka it'd be `/home/luka/Documents`, but you've got the idea.